# openlayers image layer stretch with no blur effect

Tags: image, openlayers, zooming, gwt-openlayers

I use an Image Layer to draw some data at specific locations on my web application using gwt-openlayers. Assume the original image is 400x400 pixels. Whem I zoom in the map, the image is stretched. The problem is that the stretch effect is 'blurry'. How can I avoid this blurry effect and instruct openlayers to apply a normal 'raw' stretch on the image? Is there some options somewhere? When I say blurry, I mean this:

[image: as you can see the center of the image has blended colors while the original image is exactly formed by four sub squares with four different colors]

The image above demonstrate the concept. I have a 400x400 pixels image. The image is formed by 4 sub squares 200x200 pixels each. Top left square is blue, top right is red, bottom left is yellow and bottom right is red. When I draw this image as an image layer in openlayers and I zoom the map, the center of the image gets blurry and the four colors are blended. Is there a way to avoid this blur effect and have a 'raw' stretch? Thanks.

Here's the code (in gwt-openlayers) I use to create the image layer:

```
org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.layer.ImageOptions imgOptions = new org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.layer.ImageOptions();
imgOptions.setIsBaseLayer(false);
imgOptions.setTransitionEffect(TransitionEffect.RESIZE);
imgOptions.setAlwaysInRange(true);
imgOptions.setLayerOpacity(0.7);
imgOptions.setProjection("EPSG:900913");

imgLayer = new org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.layer.Image("my_name",
                    null, bounds, new Size(1, 1), imgOptions);
map.addLayer(imgLayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a point with an external graphic to solve this.
Resize the external graphic on zoom.

See the showcase: http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=Image%20vector